# Password won't encrypt properly (carrying over too many characters)

Tags: c++, string, encryption, c-strings

I'm writing a password program. Program starts by asking user to input password that includes 8 or more characters that includes a character and punctuation.

After that the program will "encrypt" the password by moving the second half of the password to the front adding a "+" in the middle and then appending the first half to the end.

The problem I'm getting is that whenever I enter a password that is of odd characters it copies the last character twice and is breaking my program. How do I fix this? I know I have to add a condition incase there are odd characters but idk what it should include. Here is my code:

```
// write a function to encrypt the password:
// return a dynamically allocated C string of the exact size (no extra room) with:
// the last half of the password, the + symbol, and then the first half of the password
char * encrypt (char pw[])
 {
int exactsize = strlen(pw) + 2;
char * encPW = new char[exactsize];
int mid = exactsize / 2;


strcpy(encPW, pw + mid);
strcat(encPW, "+");
strncat(encPW, pw, exactsize - mid);

return encPW;

 }

 // write the same (overloaded) function for a C++ String
 char * encrypt (string pw)
 {
int exactsize = pw.length() + 2;
char * encPW = new char[exactsize];
int mid = exactsize / 2;

string temp(pw, mid);
string temp2(pw, 0 ,mid);
temp = temp + "+" + temp2;

strcpy(encPW, temp.c_str());


return encPW;
}

here is the output i am getting and what i am talking about:
Enter your password: salehrocks93
add punctuation
Enter your password: salehrocks93/
Valid password format. Encrypting...

Encrypted password: cks93/+salehroc

Enter your new password: salehrocks93/
New Encrypted password: cks93/+salehro
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

when it asks for the password the first time and encrypts it the c is repeated twice

Comment: What is the desired behavior when the password is of odd length? For example what should the encryption of 'passwords' be?

Comment: A few non-answer observations: 1. Your API is imbalanced: the function allocates memory but requires the caller to release it - this is a bad practice. 2. Your overload takes a `std::string` by *value* - that means it creates a local copy when invoked, which makes having it as an overload a poor design choice. Make it a `const std::string&` to take it by reference. 3. `temp = temp + "+" + temp2;` think about what that does...

Comment: @Eric the encryption of the passwords should always be the same take the second half of the password put it in front of the first and add a "+" in the middle.

Comment: @kfsone i am only having a problem with my first function when i do it in C string the C++ string isnt giving me any trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do I like to do with problems like these? **Step through them.** I find it often helps to draw things out. Good ole' **pen and paper debugging**. If you can't figure it out on paper, how will you figure it out in a computer?! *There are so many wires!*

So. Let's step through it. First we'll need to pick a fake argument to pass it.

---

For the purposes of this demonstration, let's use the C-style, NULL-terminated string "PASSWOR". If I were to draw this array it might look like this:

```
['P'].['A'].['S'].['S'].['W'].['O'].['R']
```

Ok, now onto your code.

```
char * encrypt (char pw[])
 {
  int exactsize = strlen(pw) + 2;
  char * encPW = new char[exactsize];
  int mid = exactsize / 2;
```

Here we are at the start of your function. You've declared a variable **exactsize** using the string's length and a **magic number**. My guess is you are using this magic number to account for the NULL terminator and the '+' you wish to add.

So, with our fake argument "PASSWOR", we should get a strlen() of **7**, making our 'exactsize' **9**.

Then you allocate an array of characters, **encPW**, as this new 'exact' size. Here is what encPW now looks like, as an array of characters

```
// initial value
[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ]
// with indices
  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

Then you declare **mid**, which I think we can safely assume means the midpoint. It's a little tricky though because you are determining mid in reference to your new size. But let's stick to the code at hand. Because our **exactsize** is **9**, then mid should be **4.5**. But it's an integer, so the end result is **4**. We proceed.

```
strcpy(encPW, pw + mid);
```

Now you strcpy into the destination of encPW, starting at `pw + mid`. `pw + mid` gives us a pointer to the character **'W'** from the original string. It will copy up to and including the NULL terminator.

```
// now what do we have?
['W'].['O'].['R'].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ]
```

Then you append the **'+'** to the string:

```
strcat(encPW, "+");
// now what do we have?
[ 'W' ].[ 'O' ].[ 'R' ].[ '+' ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ]
```

Finally, you call *strncat()*, which appends *num* characters to a C-style string, **plus**  a NULL terminator.

You are telling it to write `exactsize - mid` characters to the string. Since **exactsize** is 9, and **mid** is 4, we are telling it to write **5** characters.

> **As we saw above, strncat also writes a NULL terminator. That's 6 characters! However, as we can see (by counting the 0's left in the
>   string above), there are only 5 characters left before we are writing
>   into memory that isn't ours!**

Here's what happens under the hood (at a high level)

```
strncat(encPW, pw, exactsize - mid)
// strncat tries to write this stuff at the end
[ 'W' ].[ 'O' ].[ 'R' ].[ '+' ].[ 'P' ].[ 'A' ].[ 'S' ].[ 'S' ].[ 'W' ].[ 0 ]
                                                                         .^
                                      Uh oh, somebody call the memory police!
```

However, even if we didn't write into scary, mysterious memory, the algorithm still appears fundamentally flawed, because one of our characters appears twice!

---

My question for you: what is **mid**? How did you intend to use it when you declared it?

So now, we come up with our simple pen and paper fix.

---

How I would solve this:

```
int mid = strlen(pw) / 2;
```

And for your strncat() I would use

```
strncat(encPW, pw, mid)
```

---

This solves a few problems for us. Let's use two examples, "PASSWOR" and "PASSWORD".

> Using **"PASSWOR"**, mid would be 3
>
> pw + mid would be **'S'** (the second s)
>
> After the strcpy encPW would be "SWOR"
>
> After the first strcat, it would be "SWOR+"
>
> After `strncat(encPW, pw, mid)` it would be "SWOR+PAS".

Ideal, yes?

> Using **"PASSWORD"**, mid would be 4
>
> pw + mid would be **'W'**
>
> After strcpy encPW would be "WORD"
>
> After the first strcat, it would be "WORD+"
>
> After `strncat(encPW, pw, mid)` it would be "WORD+PASS".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void encrypt(const std::string& password)
{
    size_t exactSize = password.length() + sizeof('+') + sizeof('\0');
    size_t mid = exactSize / 2;

    std::cout << "password = " << password
              << ", exactSize = " << exactSize
              << ", mid = " << mid
              << ", password[0,mid) = " << password.substr(0, mid)
              << ", password[mid,npos) = " << password.substr(mid, std::string::npos)
              << '\n';

    std::string t1(password, mid);
    std::string t2(password, 0, mid);

    std::cout << "t1 = " << t1 << ", t2 = " << t2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    encrypt("12345678");
    encrypt("123456789");

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output http://ideone.com/fork/Y9GsHM

```
password = 12345678,  exactSize = 10, mid = 5, password[0,mid) = 12345, password[mid,npos) = 678
t1 = 678, t2 = 12345
password = 123456789, exactSize = 11, mid = 5, password[0,mid) = 12345, password[mid,npos) = 6789
t1 = 6789, t2 = 12345
```

The problem is that `exactSize` is the *result* size including the '+' and '\0' and not the size of the source string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void encrypt(const std::string& password)
{
    size_t mid = password.length() / 2;
    size_t exactSize = password.length() + sizeof('+') + sizeof('\0');

    std::cout << "password = " << password
              << ", exactSize = " << exactSize
              << ", mid = " << mid
              << ", password[0,mid) = " << password.substr(0, mid)
              << ", password[mid,npos) = " << password.substr(mid, std::string::npos)
              << '\n';

    std::string t1(password, mid);
    std::string t2(password, 0, mid);

    std::cout << "t1 = " << t1 << ", t2 = " << t2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    encrypt("12345678");
    encrypt("123456789");

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/E5YFKm

Your C-string version is pretty dodgy too, I made a matching C-string version of the above code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void encrypt(const char* password)
{
    size_t len = strlen(password);
    size_t allocSize = strlen(password) + sizeof('+') + sizeof('\0');
    size_t mid = len / 2;

    char left[16];
    char right[16];

    strncpy(left, password, len - mid);
    left[len - mid] = '\0';
    strcpy(right, password + mid);

    std::cout << "password = " << password
              << ", len = " << len
              << ", remainder = " << (len - mid)
              << ", mid = " << mid
              << ", left = " << left
              << ", right = " << right
              << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "begin\n";
    encrypt("12345678");
    encrypt("123456789");

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/O6Na9t